# Setting up Git: Init Git on active servers

Tags: git, github

So I'm looking to sync my live server with my Git repo. This server is already populated with files and the such, and I'm looking for any ideas to best implement Git on it. Below is just a small explanation to help paint a picture of what I'm dealing with.

My repo was originally pushed from a development server which was a copy of the live server. Now that the repo is created, I need to sync up the live server as well.

If I clone the repo, won't that cause conflict with all the files that already live on the server? Do I need to delete all the files that Git is tracking on the live server, then clone it so it pulls in fresh from the repo?

Thanks for your time, and your suggestions are most appreciated.

Comment: My solution was to first stash, then pull.

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you're proposing is fine.

Although you should consider setting up a more sophisticated deployment system (ie. using a deployment automation tool) and also using different branches (I'm using `live` and the development branch is the `master`).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend on working with branches.
first you will need to set up the master branch and then to create your other branches.

You need it so you can have shared parent (commit id) for the 2 branches.

If you will use branched they can be fully separated and you can decide which files you want import to your server and which one to leave in the development branch.

You can take a look and get ideas from gitFlow

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

git flow handle such a case by having different branches - in your case it can be development and server branches